# How can I achieve Multiline Header in the QTableView

Tags: python, pyqt

I want to achieve a table header like this[see the pic ] use the PyQt.
But the default QTableView can only define one row, is there some methods I can achieve this?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should use a different horizontalHeader, but am not really sure on which kind of widget you would use for that. Perhaps another table with joined cells.